# Микроразметка картинок, находящихся в background

Tags: seo, microdata

Добрый день!

Делаю микроразметку для сайта, занимающегося продажей кухонь. В карточке товара есть слайдер, картинки выводятся не тегом `img src="..."`, а как background для каскада тегов `<div>`. Я хочу передать данные о картинках поисковикам посредством микроразметки [schema.org](http://ruschema.org/Product). Но из примера в документации следует, что свойство image можно прописать внутри тега `<img>` как `property="image"`, и тогда поисковый робот считает `src` тега `img` и примет его как `url`-изображения.

Выводить скрытые теги `img src="..." property="image" >` будет накладно, т.к. сайт и так не очень быстро работает, (самопал на Zend), а картинки довольно большие. Как мне сказать роботу, что в backgound слайдера находятся те самые картинки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

    <!-- Тут что хочешь-->
    ...

    <meta itemprop="image" content="http://url/of/picture" />
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую. )

Comment: Всё получилось, спасибо!